# Get XElement by value of its attribute

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml, xelement

I've got the following XML:

```
<rootNode>
  ... some stuff
  <ReportCellRef>
    <dang n="DVCompany" h="0" u="0" o="0" fmt="0">
      ... some stuff
    </dang>
  </ReportCellRef>
</rootNode>
```

And I want get the `<dang ...> ... </dang>` node as XElement, so I can replace it with another node, provided I have the value of the `n` attribute.

I've got this code:

```
Dim nameToSearch = importNode.Attribute("n").Value
Dim replaceable = From dangToTake In xdoc.Elements("ReportCellRef") _
                  Where CStr(dangToTake.Element("dang").Attribute("n")) = nameToSearch
                  Select dangToTake

For Each nodeToReplace As XElement In replaceable
    nodeToReplace.ReplaceWith(importNode)
Next nodeToReplace
```

But the LINQ query does not yield any results... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throw a "Descendants()" call in there:

```
dim xdoc as XDocument = XDocument.Parse("<rootNode><ReportCellRef><dang n=""DVCompany"" h=""0"" u=""0"" o=""0"" fmt=""0""></dang></ReportCellRef></rootNode>")
Dim replaceable = From dangToTake In xdoc.Descendants().Elements("ReportCellRef") _
              Where dangToTake.Element("dang").Attribute("n").Value = "DVCompany"
              Select dangToTake
```

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing an XAttribute against its value.  `CStr(dangToTake.Element("dang").Attribute("n"))` does not give you the value of the attribute.  Try `dangToTake.Element("dang").Attribute("n").Value` instead.