# How do I find a specific node that matches a variable value?

Tags: xml, vb.net

Some may say this question is similar to a previous question and it is but it is also different. 
I have ObjXmlSimpleTypeDoc object which have two EnumerationValue nodes. Each of EnumerationValue have child nodes.

I just want to find the correct EnumerationValue node which has @code that matches the value in the variable strCourtNCIC. In this question strCourtNCIC= MN010015J. 
For this question strCourtNCIC hold a value MN010015J.

How do I do this in VB.NET? My VB.NET code returns Nothing for objXmlEnumerationValueNode even though I am expecting to see the node with @code = MN010015J

How do I change my VB.NET line of code to find EnumerationValue node with @code that matches strCourtNCIC value?

Here is the object ObjXmlSimpleTypeDoc

```
<SimpleTypeCompanion enumerates="CourtLocationTextType">
    <EnumerationValue code="MN010015J">
        <Text>Emily County</Text>
        <AssociatedValue type="MNCISNodeID">
            <Text>111</Text>
        </AssociatedValue>
        <AssociatedValue type="CountyName">
            <Text>Emily</Text>
        </AssociatedValue>
        <AssociatedValue type="PhoneNumber">
            <Text>724-820-7123</Text>
        </AssociatedValue>
    </EnumerationValue>
    <EnumerationValue code="DC19DAKDC">
        <Text>Pope County</Text>
        <AssociatedValue type="MNCISNodeID">
            <Text>112</Text>
        </AssociatedValue>
        <AssociatedValue type="CountyName">
            <Text>Pope</Text>
        </AssociatedValue>
    </EnumerationValue>
</SimpleTypeCompanion>
```

Here is the VB.NET code that I need help with to just get the correct EnumerationValue that matches strCourtNCIC (MN010015J).

```
    'CourtNCIC 
strCourtNCIC = objXmlMNCISData.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Case/Court/CourtNCIC").InnerText
'Access the CourtLocationTextType simple type. 
objXmlSimpleTypeDoc = Msc.Integration.CourtXml.Library.v4.SimpleType.GetCompanionFile("CourtLocationTextType")
'Get the correct EnumerationValue node that has @code =MN010015J string value
objXmlEnumerationValueNode = objXmlSimpleTypeDoc.SelectSingleNode("/SimpleTypeCompanion/EnumerationValue[@code=" + strCourtNCIC + "]/@code")
```

Comment: If `objXmlSimpleTypeDoc` is an XElement then you can use `objXmlEnumerationValueNode = objXmlSimpleTypeDoc.Elements("EnumerationValue").Where(Function(el) el.Attribute("code").Value = strCourtNCIC).ToList()`. Ref: [Get XElement by value of its attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675704/get-xelement-by-value-of-its-attribute).

Comment: objXmlSimpleTypeDoc is declared as Dim objXmlSimpleTypeDoc As System.Xml.XmlDocument. I am getting an error objXmlSimpleTypeDoc As XmlDocument  'Elements' is not a member of 'XmlDocument'

Comment: Yes, that would only have worked if objXmlSimpleTypeDoc was an XElement, but I couldn't see its declaration in the question so I could only guess.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your input on this. Based on your knowledge, what do you recommend I can do?

Comment: Have a go with `objXmlEnumerationValueNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//SimpleTypeCompanion/EnumerationValue[@code='" & strCourtNCIC & "']")`, ref: [Search XML file for nodes with specific attribute value in .NET 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14501038/1115360).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. It was the case of missing single quotes around the value!

```
objXmlEnumerationValueNode = objXmlSimpleTypeDoc.SelectSingleNode("/SimpleTypeCompanion/EnumerationValue[@code='" + strCourtORI + "']")
```